# How to make a SwiftUI NavigationLink conditional based on an Optional Object?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, observableobject

Let’s say I have a model class `Ball`, that conforms to the `ObservableObject` protocol, and I define an optional instance of it (`var ball: Ball?`).

Is there a way to trigger a `NavigationLink` to display its `destination` view based on setting the value of the optional instance? So when I `self.ball = Ball()`, a `NavigationLink` will trigger?

One problem seems to be that an optional (`Type?`) can’t be an `@ObservedObject`.

The other problem seems to be that the `isActive:` parameter for `NavigationLink` can only take a `Binding<Bool>`.

```swift
/// Contrived minimal example to illustrate the problem.
include SwiftUI

class Ball: ObservableObject {
  @Published var colour: String = "red"
  // ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
  // this won’t trigger view updates when it’s set because it’s not observed:
  var ball: Ball?

  // this line won’t compile:
  @ObservedObject var observedBall: Ball?
  //  Property type 'Ball?' does not match that of the
     // 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        // I want this to navigate to the ballView when isActive becomes true,
        // but it won’t accept the test of nil state on the optional value:
        NavigationLink(
          destination: BallView(ball: self.ball), isActive: self.ball != nil
        ) {
          EmptyView()
        } //  compiler error because `self.ball != nil` isn’t valid for `isActive:`

        // Button user taps to set the `ball`,
        // which I want to trigger the BallView to be shown.
        Button(action: { self.ball = Ball() }, label: { Text("Show Ball") })
      }
    }
  }
}

struct BallView: View {
  @ObservedObject var ball: Ball
  // typical view stuff here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best workaround I have for the above limitations involves:

- defining another ObservableObject-conforming class as a wrapper around an Optional Ball instance,
- adding a `@State var ballIsSet = false` (or `@Binding var ballIsSet: Bool`) variable to my view,
- passing in that ballIsSet boolean variable to the wrapper class object,
- then having a `didSet` function on the wrapped Ball variable that updates the passed in boolean.

Phew!

Hopefully someone knows a simpler/better way to do this…

```swift
// Still a somewhat contrived example, but it illustrates the points…

class ObservableBall: ObservableObject {
  // a closure to call when the ball variable is set
  private var whenSetClosure: ((Bool) -> Void)?
  @Published var ball: Ball? {
    didSet {
      // if the closure is assigned, call it when the ball gets set
      if let setClosure = self.whenSetClosure {
        setClosure(self.ball != nil)
      }
    }
  }
  
  init(_ ball: Ball? = nil, whenSetClosure: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.ball = ball
    self.whenSetClosure = whenSetClosure
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var observedBall = ObservableBall()
  @State var ballIsSet = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        // Navigate to the ballView when ballIsSet becomes true:
        NavigationLink(
          // we can force unwrap observedBall.ball! here
          // because this only gets called if ballIsSet is true:
          destination: BallView(ball: self.observedBall.ball!),
          isActive: $ballIsSet
        ) {
          EmptyView()
        }

        // Button user taps to set the `ball`,
        // triggering the BallView to be shown.
        Button(
          action: { self.observedBall.ball = Ball() },
          label: { Text("Show Ball") }
        )
      }
      .onAppear {
        observedBall.whenSetClosure = { isSet in
          self.ballIsSet = isSet
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [init(get:set:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(get:set:)-7ufcp) initializer of the `Binding` to activate the destination view based on the optional instance or on an arbitrary conditional logic. For example:

```
struct Ball {
  var colour: String = "red"
  // ...
}
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var ball: Ball?
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(isActive: Binding<Bool>(get: {
      ball != nil
    }, set: { _ in
      ball = nil
    })) {
      DestinationView()
    } label: {
      EmptyView()
    }
  }
}
```

I've used `struct Ball` instead of `class Ball: ObservableObject`, since `@ObservedObject ball: Ball?` represents a value semantic of type `Optional<Ball>`, thus cannot be combined with `@ObservedObject` or `@StateObject`, which are property wrappers for reference types. The value types (i.e., `Optinal<Ball>`) can be used with `@State` or `@Binding`, but this is most likely not what you want with an optional observable object.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar problem and the way I tried to get my `NavigationLink` to render based on a nullable object is to wrap around the `NavigationLink` if a optional binding to that optional object, then attach the `onAppear` callback to modify the `isActive` binding boolean to turn on the navigation link (so that it become active after it added to the view hierarchy and thus keep the transition animation)

```
class ObservableBall: ObservableObject {
  @Published var ball: Ball?
  @Published var showBallView = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var observedBall: Ball 

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        if let ball = observedBall.ball {
          NavigationLink(
            destination: BallView(ball: ball), 
            isActive: $observedBall.showBallView) 
          {
            EmptyView()
          }
          .onAppear {
            observedBall.showBallView = true
          } 
        } 
        // Button user taps to set the `ball`,
        // which I want to trigger the BallView to be shown.
        Button(action: { self.observedBall.ball = Ball() }, label: { Text("Show Ball") })
      }
    }
  }
}

struct BallView: View {
  @ObservedObject var ball: Ball
  // typical view stuff here ...
}
```